# Extract values from dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary A:

```
A = {"'Delhi-Mumbai'": {6: [3]}, "'Doon-Gurgaon'": {8: [6, 9, 8, 5], 6: [7, 1, 2]}}
```

I want to extract data from it such that I end up with this

```
extracted = {"'Delhi-Mumbai'": 6, "'Doon-Gurgaon'": [8,6]}
```

I tried running this

```
for k,v in A.items():
    for i,j in v.items():
        new[k]=i
```

but this code only returns:

```
{"'Delhi-Mumbai'": 6, "'Doon-Gurgaon'": 6}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you quoting your strings twice?

Comment: How can I change that? I am getting this kind of output from another function

Comment: Fix the other function.

Comment: use `print()` inside `for` loop to see what you have in variables -  it helps to see what is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a simple option:

```
res = {key: list(value) for key, value in A.items()}
```

if you want to fix your double-quotes in the same go you could use this:

```
res = {key[1:-1]: list(value) for key, value in A.items()}
# {'Delhi-Mumbai': [6], 'Doon-Gurgaon': [8, 6]}
```

here i just strip the first and last character of every string.

---

in your solution you overwrite `new[k] = i` for every new `i`. this way only the last one remains.

Comment: Even simpler: `{key: list(value) for key, value in A.items()}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
extracted = {k: v.keys() for k, v in A.items()}
```

This approach will always create a list for every item in the main dictionary.

If you don't wish to have a list when there is only one element you could replace the `v.keys()` with `v.keys() if len(v) > 1 else next(iter(v))`

Note that this approach will only work supposing every value in the main dictionary is another dictionary and each one of these nested dictionaries has at least one element contained.

Also, I would highly encourage you to learn about list and dictionary comprehensions in Python. Really useful and better performing approaches to create lists and dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
for k,v in A.items():
    print(k,v)
    L=[]
    for i,j in v.items():
        L.append(i)
        print(i,j)
    if len(L)==1:
        new[k]=L[0]
    else:
        new[k]=L
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one.

```
A = {"'Delhi-Mumbai'": {6: [3]}, "'Doon-Gurgaon'": {8: [6, 9, 8, 5], 6: [7, 1, 2]}}
new = {}
for k,v in A.items():
    l = []
    for i,j in v.items():
        l.append(i)
    if len(l) == 1:
        new[k] = l[0]
    else:
        new[k] = l
print(new)
```

result : `{"'Delhi-Mumbai'": 6, "'Doon-Gurgaon'": [8,6]}`